# Unresolved external symbol when putting definition in CPP file

Tags: c++

For the life of me I cannot figure out what is causing this...  I keep getting unresolved external symbol error.  However, if I put an empty definition in the header file it compiles correctly.

**WINMAIN.CPP**

```
#include "FILE_XXX.H"

int WINMAIN WinMain(...)
{
   EnableOpenTest(); // call like this
   return 0;
}
```

**FILE_WORKS_CORRECTLY.H**

```
#ifndef _FILE_WORKS_CORRECTLY_
#define _FILE_WORKS_CORRECTLY_

void EnableOpenTest() { }

#endif
```

However, when I do something like this (correctly), it does not work and I get a compile-time error.

**FILE_DOES_NOT_WORK_CORRECTLY.H**

```
#ifndef _FILE_DOES_NOT_WORK_CORRECTLY_
#define _FILE_DOES_NOT_WORK_CORRECTLY_

void EnableOpenTest();

#endif
```

**FILE_DOES_NOT_WORK_CORRECTLY.CPP**

```
#include "FILE_DOES_NOT_WORK_CORRECTLY.H"

void EnableOpenTest() { /* do work here */ }
```

UPDATE:
Upon further investigation, I found the issue has to do with me having multiple projects in the same solution. I then try to reference a function in one project from another project. Obviously I'm doing this incorrectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but don't use leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter for any symbol name, those are reserved for "the implementation" (compiler and standard library). See [this old question and its answers for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: As for your problem, when you get the errors, you *do* build with both source files? Both source files are in your actual project tree in Visual Studio (which I assume you use) and not only in the same directory on disk?

Comment: Correct.  The CPP file is in the source part of the project and the H file is in the header file portion.

Comment: Does your WINMAIN.CPP include the file with EnableOpenTest?

Comment: @Dreggman45 Yessir with the #include "blah.h"

Comment: I ran the code you gave me, it works alright... Can you show a part of your actual code so I can help you more definitely?

Comment: @Dreggman45 It's a large-scale project actually (Falcon 4.0 source code).  Upon further investigation, I found the issue has to do with me having multiple projects in the same solution.  I then try to reference a function in one project from another project.  Obviously I'm doing this incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

1. Additional projects needed to be static library (main project .exe)
2. Added References of library projects to main project

Obviously the file structure caused a lot of these issues.

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake i see is that in the cpp file you need to include the return type as well. It should be

```
void EnableOpenTest()
{
    //Enter Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of `FILE_DOES_NOT_WORK_CORRECTLY.CPP`:

```
EnableOpenTest(){ /* do work here */ }
```

must be

```
void EnableOpenTest(){ /* do work here */ }
```

Looks like your compiler sets the missing return type to `int` instead of yelling at you with a error message.

You should turn on compiler warnings, it would allow you to notice such errors very quickly.

---

Also, inside of `FILE_WORKS_CORRECTLY.H` you have another error:

```
void EnableOpenTest() { }
```

must be

```
inline void EnableOpenTest() { }
```

Otherwise it will trigger a error message if this header is included twice (i.e. in more that one `.cpp` file).

Comment: Doh!  Sorry, I do have it as void (I just didn't do a good job copying it over for this question).  So we are back to square 1.